# Play framework GuiceApplicationBuilder not loading enabled module configs

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest, playframework-2.5, silhouette

I'm trying to test some actions. They require my security stuff which I've created using Silhouette.

I have a module to configure the DI for Silhouette in `security.Module`, and in my `conf/application.conf` file I have the line:

```
play.modules.enabled += "security.Module"
```

When I run my tests I get an error saying:

```
No implementation for com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Silhouette<security.JwtEnv> was bound.
```

If I set a breakpoint in my `security.Module` class, it's never triggered. However if I set a breakpoint in my main `Module` class it is. So I can see that my `security.Module` is never being loaded despite the docs for [GuiceApplicationBuilder](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice#Loaded-modules) saying enabled modules are loaded automatically.

Here's how I'm configuring `GuiceApplicationBuilder` in my test class (based on scalatest):

```
class TestUserController extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerTest with Results {

  val identity = UserDao(
    id = Some(10),
    email = Some("testuser@example.com"),
    createdAt = DateTime.parse("2016-11-11T11:11:11")
  )

  val loginInfo = LoginInfo("credentials", identity.email.get)

  implicit val env = FakeEnvironment[JwtEnv](Seq(loginInfo -> identity))

  implicit override def newAppForTest(td: TestData) = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .overrides(bind[UsersBlockedRepo].to[MockUsersBlockedRepo])
    .build
//...
}
```

What am I missing to get `GuiceApplicationBuilder` to load my security module?

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this. The problem was that my `security.Module` took constructor args:

```
class Module(environment: PlayEnvironment,
         configuration: Configuration) extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {...}
```

Removing those fixed it.

Comment: I am having same issue despite having constructor args for Module. I am using `GuiceOneAppPerSuite` . Application works normally but while testing it doesn't load my module class despite being enabled in application.conf. `mvn test` works but running a single test from eclipse fails

Comment: I just fixed it by correcting output folder for app, conf and test directory under build path. Somehow I had them going to separate directory then usual target dir of maven.